Minting Metaplex NFTs in an Anchor Program using PDAs
I am trying to mint Metaplex NFTs in an Anchor program. Unfortunately it seems that the provided seeds don't result in a valid address.
Here is my program:

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{Mint, Token};
use mpl_token_metadata::{
    accounts::{Metadata, MasterEdition},
    instructions::{CreateV1CpiBuilder},
    types::{PrintSupply, TokenStandard},
};
use mpl_token_metadata::ID as MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_ID;
mod events;
use crate::events::NFTCreationEvent;

// use mpl_token_metadata::instruction::{create_metadata_accounts_v2, create_master_edition_v3};
// use mpl_token_metadata::state::{Creator, DataV2};
// use solana_program::program::invoke;

declare_id!("DwUgmXJmqnJqDcMuRE61AgbBSvfFY7gDmu6W55V7XPfd");

#[program]
mod factory {
    use super::*;
    pub fn hello_world(_ctx: Context<Hello>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Hello world, from solana smart contract");
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn mint_nft(_ctx: Context<MintNFT>, token_params: InitTokenParams) -> Result<()> {

        let mint = &_ctx.accounts.mint;
        let payer = &_ctx.accounts.payer;
        let token_program: &Program<'_, Token> = &_ctx.accounts.token_program;
        let token_metadata_program = &_ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program;
        let system_program = &_ctx.accounts.system_program;
        let metadata=&_ctx.accounts.metadata;
        let master_edition=&_ctx.accounts.master_edition;
        
        msg!("id:                       {}", token_params.id);
        // msg!("payer:                 {}", _ctx.accounts.payer.key().to_string());
        msg!("mint:                     {}", _ctx.accounts.mint.key().to_string());
        // msg!("mint:                  {}", _ctx.accounts.metadata.key().to_string());

        // metadata.symbol=String::from("VLT");
        // metadata.name=format!("{} {}", String::from("token_"), metadata.id);
        let name: String = format!("{} {}", String::from("token_"), token_params.id);
        let symbol: String = String::from("VLT");

        // https://docs.rs/mpl-core/latest/mpl_core/instructions/struct.CreateV1CpiBuilder.html
        // https://developers.metaplex.com/guides/rust/how-to-cpi-into-a-metaplex-program
        // mpl-core ref: https://docs.rs/mpl-core/0.7.0/mpl_core/instructions/index.html
        
        // Derive the bump for master_edition and metadata PDAs
        let (master_edition_id, master_edition_bump) = MasterEdition::find_pda(&mint.key());
        let (metadata_id, metadata_bump) = Metadata::find_pda(&mint.key());

        msg!("master_edition_id:        {}", master_edition_id.key().to_string());
        msg!("metadata_id:              {}", metadata_id.key().to_string());
        msg!("master_edition_bump:      {}", master_edition_bump.to_string());
        msg!("metadata_bump:            {}", metadata_bump.to_string());

        let mint_id = mint.key();

        // Construct the signers array with the proper seed and bump for each PDA
        let signers: &[&[&[u8]]] = &[
            // Seed and bump for the mint PDA
            &["mint".as_bytes(), token_params.id.as_bytes(), &[_ctx.bumps.mint]],
            // Seed and bump for the master edition PDA
            &["metadata".as_bytes(), MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_ID.as_ref(), mint_id.as_ref(), "edition".as_bytes(), &[master_edition_bump]],
            // // Seed and bump for the metadata PDA
            &["metadata".as_bytes(), MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_ID.as_ref(), mint_id.as_ref(), &[metadata_bump]],
        ];
                
        let _ = CreateV1CpiBuilder::new(&token_metadata_program.to_account_info())
                                    .payer(&payer.to_account_info())
                                    .mint(&mint.to_account_info(), true)
                                    .update_authority(&mint.to_account_info(), true) // Who can update the metadata
                                    .authority(&mint.to_account_info())
                                    .name(name)
                                    .symbol(symbol)
                                    .uri(token_params.uri)
                                    .seller_fee_basis_points(0)
                                    .metadata(&metadata.to_account_info())
                                    .system_program(&system_program.to_account_info())
                                    .sysvar_instructions(&system_program.to_account_info())
                                    .print_supply(PrintSupply::Limited(1)) 
                                    .master_edition(Some(&master_edition.to_account_info())) //     https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/print
                                    .token_standard(TokenStandard::NonFungible)
                                    .invoke_signed(signers)?;

        // Emit the NFTCreationEvent
        emit!(NFTCreationEvent {
            mint: _ctx.accounts.mint.key(),
            owner: _ctx.accounts.payer.key(),
            id: token_params.id
        });

        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Hello {}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(
    params: InitTokenParams
)]
pub struct MintNFT<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init, // the program creates this account
        seeds = [b"mint", params.id.as_bytes()],    // the PDA is seeded with the token ID to ensure uniqueness
        bump,
        payer = payer,
        mint::decimals = 0,
        mint::authority = mint,
    )]
    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

    /// CHECK: address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=Metadata::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub metadata: AccountInfo<'info>,

    // /// CHECK: Master edition account required for the NFT
    // #[account(mut)]
    // pub master_edition: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
    /// CHECK: address
    #[account(
        mut,
        address=MasterEdition::find_pda(&mint.key()).0,
    )]
    pub master_edition: AccountInfo<'info>,

    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,

    /// CHECK: Token metadata program, no validation needed since we will check it manually in code
    // #[account(address = TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID)]
    pub token_metadata_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,
}

#[derive(AnchorSerialize, AnchorDeserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct InitTokenParams {
    pub id: String,
    pub uri: String,
    // pub symbol: String,
    // pub name: String
}

And my test script:
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program, web3} from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Factory } from "../target/types/factory";
import { PublicKey, Keypair, LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, Connection} from "@solana/web3.js";
import { TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, createMint, getAccount, Account } from "@solana/spl-token";
import { assert } from "chai";  
const { SystemProgram } = web3;

describe("factory", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  console.log(`Connection: ${provider.connection.rpcEndpoint}`)

  const program = anchor.workspace.Factory as Program<Factory>;

  // Metaplex Constants
  const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = new web3.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s");

  // Create keypairs for the payer and mint accounts
  const payer = Keypair.generate();
  const mint = Keypair.generate();

  it("Create an asset", async () => {

    await checkAccounts(provider.connection);

    // Airdrop SOL to payer for testing
    const airdropSignature = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(payer.publicKey, 5e9);
    await provider.connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature, "confirmed");
    const balance = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(payer.publicKey)
    console.log(`Balance for ${payer.publicKey}: ${balance.lamports/LAMPORTS_PER_SOL}`)

    // Create the InitTokenParams struct
      const token_params = {
        id: "1234",
        uri: "https://example.com/metadata.json", // Replace with your metadata URI
    };

    const [mintPDA, mintBump] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from("mint"), 
        Buffer.from(token_params.id)
      ],
      program.programId
    );

    // Derive the metadata account PDA
    const [metadataPDA, metadataBump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    // Derive the master edition PDA
    const [masterEditionPDA, masterEditionPDABump] = web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [
        Buffer.from('metadata'),
        TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID.toBuffer(),
        mintPDA.toBuffer(),
        Buffer.from('edition'),
      ],
      TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    console.log("\nAddresses")
    console.log(`provider account:              ${provider.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`payer account:                 ${payer.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`mint account:                  ${mint.publicKey}`)
    console.log(`Token Program:                 ${TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID}`)
    console.log(`Token Metadata Program:        ${TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID}`)
    console.log(`System Program:                ${SystemProgram.programId}`)
    console.log(`mint PDA Program:              ${mintPDA}`)
    console.log(`master edition PDA Program:    ${masterEditionPDA}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Program:          ${metadataPDA}`)

    console.log("\nBumps")
    console.log(`master edition PDA Bump:       ${masterEditionPDABump}`)
    console.log(`metadata PDA Bump:             ${metadataBump}`)
    // console.log(`metadataPDA account: ${metadataPDA}`)
    
    // Call the mint_nft function
    await program.methods
        .mintNft(token_params) // Call the function with the InitTokenParams struct
        .accounts({
            payer: payer.publicKey,
            mint: mintPDA,
            metadata: metadataPDA,
            masterEdition: masterEditionPDA,
            rent: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_RENT_PUBKEY,
            systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            tokenMetadataProgram: TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
        })
        .signers([payer])
        .rpc();
  });
});

// function to check that external programs are present in the test environment
async function checkAccounts (connection: Connection){
  let accountInfo
  let id: string
  // check that external accounts are available in this session
  try{
    id = 'metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s'
    accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id));
    console.log(accountInfo)
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    console.warn(`metaplex token metadata program @ ${id} not found\n${error}`)
  }
  
  try{
    id = 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA'
    accountInfo = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey(id));
    console.log(accountInfo)
  } catch (error: unknown) {
    console.warn(`spl token program @ ${id} not found\n${error}`)
  }
}

Here the error log:
Addresses
provider account:              EHbbJkVGh23Hd2GPcjZTMbror37MWF7tcfoyz5Ct2XRP
payer account:                 Em61jDPLjSAePHg2hbRscZjm6YH5zN1JaumkHUvT1ncX
mint account:                  EYWYxm2cfKVgkYCivXxzX9C7raXBM36422CFohLXjSkZ
Token Program:                 TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA
Token Metadata Program:        metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s
System Program:                11111111111111111111111111111111
mint PDA Program:              Dorw5wkcwaankrfC8u4sRtpwVNQ2aC6gXJXqSwQEFgHC
master edition PDA Program:    B5FrJNnvyN9ebAQbZL63gzLvMqfgPQUGsEZ3ZmYd8RXJ
metadata PDA Program:          EzKWoUop9uL5Tx7TMR9yBJZggxairLYosjRdhbkcK4D4

Bumps
master edition PDA Bump:       253
metadata PDA Bump:             255
    1) Create an asset


  0 passing (199ms)
  1 failing

  1) factory
       Create an asset:
     Error: Simulation failed. 
Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete. 
Logs: 
[
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2780 of 187719 compute units",
  "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success",
  "Program log: id:                       1234",
  "Program log: mint:                     Dorw5wkcwaankrfC8u4sRtpwVNQ2aC6gXJXqSwQEFgHC",
  "Program log: master_edition_id:        B5FrJNnvyN9ebAQbZL63gzLvMqfgPQUGsEZ3ZmYd8RXJ",
  "Program log: metadata_id:              EzKWoUop9uL5Tx7TMR9yBJZggxairLYosjRdhbkcK4D4",
  "Program log: master_edition_bump:      253",
  "Program log: metadata_bump:            255",
  "Program DwUgmXJmqnJqDcMuRE61AgbBSvfFY7gDmu6W55V7XPfd consumed 71715 of 200000 compute units",
  "Program DwUgmXJmqnJqDcMuRE61AgbBSvfFY7gDmu6W55V7XPfd failed: Could not create program address with signer seeds: Provided seeds do not result in a valid address"
]. 
Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
      at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:6043:13)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5999:20)
      at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:377:21)
      at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:163:14)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)

I'm testing the program on a local validator that I set up by loading the bpf in this way
solana-test-validator \
--bpf-program --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s ./tests/metaplex_token_metadata_program.so \
--bpf-program --bpf-program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA ./tests/spl_token_program.so \
--bpf-program --bpf-program CoREENxT6tW1HoK8ypY1SxRMZTcVPm7R94rH4PZNhX7d ./tests/mpl_core_program.so \
--bpf-program --bpf-program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb ./tests/token_2022_program.so \
--bpf-program --bpf-program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL ./tests/associated_token_program.so \
--reset

Debugging I checked that the program was able to reconstruct correctly metadata pda and master edition pda (id and bump). I'm therefore sure that I am consifuring the right signers for invoke_signed. What I am doing wrong?
Thank you very much in advance for the help!
